# Can I make a certain function globally available inside a React application?

Tags: reactjs

It is a common practice to pass in the form of a prop, from a root component A, to a subcomponent B, a function that will change the state of A. Like so:

```
class App extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: 'foo'
    };
    this.handleNameChange = this.handleNameChange.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (<NameChanger name={this.state.name} onNameChange={this.handleNameChange} />)
  }

  handleNameChange: function(newName) {
    this.setState({
      name: newName
    });
  }
}
```

Now as you can see `NameChanger` is one level down only so not a big issue there. But what if it had been down 3 or even 4 levels? We would have had to pass it down the chain of components and that bothers me big time. Is there a way to make a function globally available within the app?

I looked at `Context` (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) but I am not sure it is the right design choice for globally available functions. Or is it?

Thanks

Comment: You could use something like Redux, where you can define actions which can be called in any connected component.

Comment: Yes, this is a case context API is intended for.

Comment: @estus so you are saying Context is meant to be use to share functions as well and not just plain data?

Answer (score 0):

> In a typical React application, data is passed top-down (parent to
>   child) via props, but this can be cumbersome for certain types of
>   props (e.g. locale preference, UI theme) that are required by many
>   components within an application. Context provides a way to share
>   values like these between components without having to explicitly pass
>   a prop through every level of the tree.

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using Redux or Mobx(very easy to start with) as state management library to solve this problem.

Comment: I do not need state in that sense. I have a <Loader/> component that relies on the state of the main component in the app to decide whether or not to display. From every component issuing actions for the store I want to go showSpinner() without having to pass that function from the top component all the way down. Context works just fine for that but I was wondering if there are better ways.